# Query title starting with a given prefix via WS

Tags: rally

I am using SOAP webservice to retrieve data from Rally platform via Java application.

I would like to get all the user stories (HierarchicalRequirement) whose title starts with a given prefix, lets say title="aaaa - blablabla" and I want to query all the US with title starting with "aaaa".

Is it possible? Is it possible use regex as parameters for queries?

Thanks in advance!

R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSAPI supports a contains operator which will get you pretty close, but not regex at this time.

Comment: The problem is that contains operator would also include titles with the string appearing in the middle/end of the title' like, using the same sample above, "blablabla - aaaa - blabla". Is it? If yes, the solution is not sound enough for me :(

Comment: We always welcome input on how we can improve our Web Services Api. The best way to give us this feedback is by creating an idea at http://ideas.rallydev.com/

Comment: I guess you're probably better off using the Pattern and Matcher classes in Java to "manually" filter the results returned, using the contains operator. That would probably leave you to deal with the smallest dataset.

Comment: Using the pattern&Matcher Java would mean to retrieve anyway all the US from Rally and then find the required ones. Not very performant...